# Exclude subdomain from intent filter

Tags: android, intentfilter

I am using my app with the following intent filter:

```
 <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="*.myhost.com"
                    android:pathPattern=".*"
                    android:scheme="https" />
 </intent-filter>
```

I would like to open all links with that domain in our app, except for one specific subdomain like

```
subdomain.myhost.com
```

How can I exclude the subdomain here?

Comment: i am not sure if there is any tag for it but you can check the url in oncreate method of your activity before setContentView method and finish the activity .